# Meaning of the phrase "have something on" in context

Tags: meaning, idioms

Here is the sentence I am puzzled with:

> - "If you have an ugly handwriting read on, there might be more to your scrawl than meets the eye."

Does it mean when you have to read something? What does "on" mean there?

Comment: If you have ugly handwriting, read on. There might be more to  your scrawl than meets the eye. Read on=continue reading, drive on=continue driving. These online sites have terrible punctuation. No one rereads them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Read on" is an idiom meaning "Continue reading".

It means "If your handwriting is ugly, you might find this article interesting or useful".

I find "an ugly handwriting" strange: I would say "ugly handwriting" without the article. But I can just about accept that version.